# Position three applications in a 1280×720 frame

Tags: macos, applescript

For a screencast I'd like to have a script which sets up the desktop working environment. Here is what I have so fare:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --incognito
osascript -e "tell application \"Chrome\" to set the bounds of the first window to {0, 10, 790, 500}"
```

What do I have to add to get two Terminal windows on the right side of the Chrome window as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Everything should fit into a 1280x720 frame.

Bonus: How can I set the font size in the Terminals by the same script?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply coordinates to terminal windows as well:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script
    set bounds of window 1 to {0, 10, 790, 500}
    set bounds of window 2 to {0, 10, 790, 790}
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do all of this in vanilla Applescript:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
    set bounds of window 1 to {0, 10, 790, 500}
end tell

set myFontSize to 12
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat while ((count windows) < 2)
        set theWindow to do script "" --Opens a new window. For some reason 'make new window' doesn't work.
        set font size of window 1 to myFontSize
    end repeat
    set bounds of window 1 to {790, 10, 1280, 360}
    set bounds of window 2 to {790, 360, 1280, 720}
end tell
```

Comment: You are making 3 terminal windows with that script instead of 2.

Comment: @adayzdone, you're right. I already had Terminal running, so it only created two. If it has to launch, it creates one when it opens. I've fixed the script to always create two windows.